# SIFT in opencv does not work properly

Tags: opencv, parameters, sift

I'm working with opencv and SIFT in python.

Starting from typical examples I have really problems to find  objects with a clear (in my opinion) scene. It seems to be a matter of scaling or possibly only the wrong parameters.

I try to find this [object](https://pasteboard.co/HjDOUBU.png) in this [image](https://pasteboard.co/HjDPEow.png) but only get this [result](https://pasteboard.co/HjDQ1FS.jpg).

Basically I work with:

```
dect = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(nOctaveLayers=5)
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(crossCheck=False) 
M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC , 5.0)
```

I'm really desperate since sometimes (with other, similar object [rulers]) it works and sometimes not, even if the situation is visually clear.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is possible to match your object and scene using SIFT or other detector/descriptor pairs. Your object is perfect black-and-white but your scene is not.

For playing around with matching parameters and methods, I recommend Find-Object (http://introlab.github.io/find-object/).

Perhaps you have to prepare your scene image somehow. E.g. Using threshold to generate a bw image. I did it when searching Photomodeller markers (http://www.photomodeler.com/products/pm_automation.html) in images. An adaptive threshold (https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) worked best.

You may took at look at marker detection algorithms. E.g https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html. If you have a target with known marker positions, you can extract scale.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I approached quite naive, i.e. no image preparation except  bilinear filtering. I didn't know, that a bw object in a colored scene is difficult to find. I thought it is sufficient to have unique shapes in the object. There was no description in the web about what is suited for SIFT, ORB, ... and what not. So I try your suggestions.

Comment: Hmmm ... depending on the parameters, for the object all black areas are lost with adaptive threshold and only edges remain. For the image, after adaptive threshold (because of different size and some noise) there are black areas remaining and no matching is found. I thought this would be easier.

Comment: The question for me is: what type of marker with a comparable size would be easiest to find? The ruler needs to be in the image  but I want to extract the resolution automatically.

Comment: Thank you. Despite reading tons of infos and books on opencv I didn't know aruco. Sounds interesting.